# Why does the msvc linker produce such a large exectuable when invoked from the command line?

Tags: c, visual-studio, linker

I am using Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27041.0 both from the command line and via a Visual Studio project.

I am compiling and linking the following well-known program residing in a file called `HelloWorld.c`:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    printf("Hello World !\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The sizes of the respective *.exe files differ in a remarkable way:

a) Compiled and linked as a VS project using the default linker options from the VS Debug Build:

```
/OUT:"D:\HelloWorld.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"D:\00_HelloWorld.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG:FASTLINK /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"D:\00_HelloWorld.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\00_HelloWorld.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

38,400 HelloWorld.exe
```

b) Compiled and linked on the command line:

```
link /OUT:HelloWorld.exe HelloWorld.obj

102,400 HelloWorld.exe
```

I tried to figure out which of the additional linker options that VS provided could lead to the smaller executable, but could not find any, especially as /OPT:ICF and /OPT:REF (the ones that seemed to be the most likely candidates in my opinion) are enabled automatically when `link.exe` is invoked at the command line, as it says here: [/OPT (Optimizations) MSVC Linker Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/opt-optimizations?view=msvc-170)

Can anybody explain these different sizes ?

EDIT:

The program was compiled using

a)

```
/JMC /permissive- /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\00_HelloWorld.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

b)

```
cl /c HelloWorld.c
```

Comment: *Compiled and linked* - you showed only the linking. How do you compile?

Comment: In project setting > link > advanced it show the command line used for linking. Copy/paste this into a MCVC developer command prompt and test it.  If it gives the same result as the IDE start removing some of them.

Comment: You show the very different command lines, especially /Od and ask why the results are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the /MD compiler(!) option that is responsible for the different sizes.

Compiling the above program like so:

```
cl /c /MD HelloWorld.c
```

and linking it in the same way like above:

```
link /OUT:HelloWorld.exe HelloWorld.obj
```

yields the following executable:

```
 8,192 HelloWorld.exe
```

The /MD option instructs the compiler to produce an object file with a built-in library name `MSVCRTD.lib` that acts as am internmediate layer between the program and the CRT residing in a DLL called `MSVCRversionnumber.DLL`. (See also here for more information: [/MD option MSVC compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-170)). Not using this option results in a executable with statically linked CRT libs, hence the larger size.

Note that this way of compiling and linking C/C++ programs does require the existence of the aforementioned DLL on the target platform (including version number).